Connecting to two different networks simultaneously using two network adapters to access Internet
Description

I have two wifi adapters, each one is connected two a different network, while each network is connected to the Internet.
The two networks have the same network mask and my computer has the same IP on each. i.e. 255.255.255.0 default gateway 192.168.1.1 IP 192.168.1.20
I use Kubuntu 22.04

Requirement
I need my computer to get Internet access via the two networks simultaneously. In other words, like happened in download managers apps, it could able to use multiple connections via the two networks at the same time.
Question
Does it possible? To make the network manager to work as a router that utilize the multiple Internet connections simultaneously to get better download speed!

Your condition 2 (same IP on both)  seems to be a violation of network standards.

@waltinator but the two each of them in totally different networks! However, do you recommend that I just change the the IP on one of them? for example, keep one of them as 192.168.1.20 while change the other to 192.168.1.30, for example, keeping the configurations of each network as it is but change my machine's IP there only?
